# Python Selenium - Automated login to web page

Tags: python, visual-studio, selenium

I am completely new to Python and Selenium and writing an automated login scipt to check the availability of the appointment. I wrote the belwo code to login. The issue is whenever I use the breakpoint and manually step-in the code everything runs fine. But when I run it without breakpoint it cathes the exception at "Button click failed". I also tried adding sleep timing but nothing helped. All worked with stepping-in but without the breakpoints. Any help will be appreciated :)

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

try:
    Login_Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Login'][@type='button']")
    Login_Button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Button click failed")
```

This is the button code, which I am trying to click
[image: Button element on webpage]

The exception is thrown at Line Login_button.click() with the following message

*Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (510, 497). Other element would receive the click: ...*

Answer (score 0):

Most login forms, accept an alternate way of sending the data by pressing 'Enter' after sending the credentials, if you can't find the correct `sign-in` button using the `Xpath` either (see: [How to locate elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)), then you can try replicating the `Enter` key with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
try:
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Submitting login form failed")
```

Comment: Thanks Celius,
the login form doesn't accept 'Enter', I have tried it just reloads the webpage. When I debug and step into each line, it works. This means the code finds the correct sign-in button, but when I run with the breakpoint it throws an exception which I am not able to get rid of.